# VScode document formatter is not working for Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am trying to format code in VScode by using shift + alt + f , also I tried using right click "document format" but still no success.

Answer (score 2):

```
"[dart]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

Add this to your settings.json file, after this ctrl+s will format your code.